# Can I add a custom attribute to a controller method without writing a filter?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to add attributes to my controller methods which can be inspected using reflection.

I can see how to do this by writing a filter, and I will write an empty filter if that's the only way to achieve what I want, but all I really want is a reflection-visible attribute that can be used to generate documentation. Example:

```
    [OperatorFriendlyDescription("Begin a new message from a letter template and set initial properties.")]
    public ActionResult Create(string editorName, int mastKey, ...)
```

Is there a way to get my OperatorFriendlyDescription attribute without writing a new filter?

(Alternatively, is there some other approach or documentation feature that would allow me to set an operator friendly name for individual controller methods and retrieve this with reflection?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no magical way you can use an `OperatorFriendlyDescription` attribute without defining it, but if it doesn't need Filter functionality, don't inherit from `FilterAttribute`.

If you look at the declaration of the MVC `FilterAttribute`, you will see it is just a specialized `System.Attribute`.

```
public abstract class FilterAttribute : Attribute, IMvcFilter
```

From the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.attribute(v=vs.110).aspx) we can verify `System.Attribute` is the base for all attributes.
Since you have no special functionality needed, inherit from that instead.

An example Attribute in C#

```
public class ArbitraryAttribute: Attribute
{
    public string ArbitraryData { get; private set; }
    public ArbitraryAttribute(string arbitraryData)
    {
        ArbitraryData = arbitraryData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks to you and the goat. This sounds like exactly what I wanted. Both answers good, I picked Mindor at random.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Any attribute that allows being placed on that type of method/class/property, etc., can be used.  This class has to inherit from `System.Attribute` or another class that inherits from that.

VB example, should be very similar in C#.  This one can only be placed on methods due to the attribute target attribute.  leave off the `AttributeUsage` attribute for the attribute to be used anywhere.

```
<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)>
Public Class OperatorFriendlyDescription
    Inherits System.Attribute

  Public Property Description As String

  Public Sub New(description As String)
    Me.Description = description
  End Sub

End Class
```